# How do I return a massive dynamic in mvc 4 to a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, methods

I am pulling rows from a database looking for specific columns.  Right now it's pulling 5 rows and I need to reference the correct columns for each of the rows with the model.  Here's my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Use mimetype as key to find correct rows
        var mimetype = "mcv";
        dynamic LookupData = GetVideoUrls(mimetype);
        return View(LookupData);
    }

    private dynamic GetVideoUrls(string mimetype)
    {
        var VideoService = new AppServices.Video.GetAllVideoByMimeType();
        dynamic videoFiles = VideoService.Execute(mimetype);//Execute grabs the rows from the database
        return (videoFiles);
    }
```

In my view I have:

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
```

VideoFiles returns five rows with 13 columns.  I need to access 2 of the columns for each of the five rows in the view.  How do I do this?

***Update***
Here's my model:

```
public class LoginVideoModel
{
    public LoginVideoModel(string englishurl, string spanishurl)
    {
        EnglishVideoUrl = englishurl;
        SpanishVideoUrl = spanishurl;
    }
    public string EnglishVideoUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string SpanishVideoUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class WelcomeVideoModel
{
    public WelcomeVideoModel(string englishurl, string spanishurl)
    {
        EnglishVideoUrl = englishurl;
        SpanishVideoUrl = spanishurl;
    }
    public string EnglishVideoUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string SpanishVideoUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class BenefitVideoModel
{
    public BenefitVideoModel(string englishurl, string spanishurl)
    {
        EnglishVideoUrl = englishurl;
        SpanishVideoUrl = spanishurl;
    }
    public string EnglishVideoUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string SpanishVideoUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class MyEnrollmentVideoModel
{
    public MyEnrollmentVideoModel(string englishurl, string spanishurl)
    {
        EnglishVideoUrl = englishurl;
        SpanishVideoUrl = spanishurl;
    }
    public string EnglishVideoUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string SpanishVideoUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class AdminSideVideoModel
{
    public AdminSideVideoModel(string englishurl, string spanishurl)
    {
        EnglishVideoUrl = englishurl;
        SpanishVideoUrl = spanishurl;
    }
    public string EnglishVideoUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string SpanishVideoUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps as well.

***Update***
Here's the videoservice.execute code:

```
public class GetAllVideoByMimeType
{
    public dynamic Execute(string mimetype)
    {
        return DBRepository.GetAllByCritera<DataContainers.File>("WHERE MimeType = @0", mimetype);
    }
}
```

***update 3***
Here's the repository:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Obtain one or more items from db based on Where Clase
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Table Type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="whereClause">Standard WHERE clause with paramterized statements 
    /// Example: WHERE someID=@0",args: 4
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="arguments"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetAllByCritera<T>(string whereClause, params object[] arguments)
    {
        var model = new DBTableModel<T>();
        return model.All(where: whereClause, args: arguments);

    }
```

***What if I tried this:***

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Use mimetype as key to find correct rows
        var mimetype = "mcv";
        dynamic LookupData = GetVideoUrls(mimetype);
        return View(LookupData);
    }

    private dynamic GetVideoUrls(string mimetype)
    {
        var VideoService = new AppServices.Video.GetAllVideoByMimeType();
        List<dynamic> videoFiles = VideoService.Execute(mimetype);
        ApplicationVideoModel appvids = new ApplicationVideoModel();
        dynamic LoginFiles = videoFiles.Where(v => v.OriginalFileNameWithoutExtension == "LoginController").FirstOrDefault();
        dynamic WelcomeFiles = videoFiles.Where(v => v.OriginalFileNameWithoutExtension == "WelcomeController").FirstOrDefault();
        dynamic BenefitFiles = videoFiles.Where(v => v.OriginalFileNameWithoutExtension == "BenefitController").FirstOrDefault();
        dynamic MyEnrollmentFiles = videoFiles.Where(v => v.OriginalFileNameWithoutExtension == "MyEnrollmentController").FirstOrDefault();
        dynamic AdminFiles = videoFiles.Where(v => v.OriginalFileNameWithoutExtension == "AdminSideController").FirstOrDefault();

        return LoginFiles;
    }
```

Each of the dynamics returns the row I need, but how would I send each one to the view?

Comment: Can'y you create a view model for this ?

Comment: Yes.  But how does that work with this?

Comment: Updated the original question adding the model but don't know how that works with what I am doing.

Comment: What type does `VideoService.Execute` return?

Comment: I updated the answer based on the added information

Comment: is it safe to assume that `DBTableModel<T>().All()` is actually returning IEnurmable<T>? If so then please include `DataContainers.File`

Comment: Some advice. Duck typing all those objects behind `dynamic` is only going to cause you and who ever has to maintain your code a lot of confusion when they have to keep guessing what are the available properties on returned objects.

Comment: Check out my update.  What if I used a `List<dynamic>`?  Then I could somehow parse through that list to get what I needed.  Just not sure how to return this list to the view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101704/discussion-between-nkosi-and-jeff-mcbride).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for my application:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Use mimetype as key to find correct rows
        var mimetype = "mcv";
        var VideoService = new AppServices.Video.GetAllVideoByMimeType();
        List<dynamic> videoFiles = VideoService.Execute(mimetype);
        dynamic mymodel = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
        mymodel.LoginFiles = videoFiles.Where(v => v.OriginalFileNameWithoutExtension == "LoginController").FirstOrDefault();
        mymodel.BenefitFiles = videoFiles.Where(v => v.OriginalFileNameWithoutExtension == "BenefitController").FirstOrDefault();
        mymodel.WelcomeFiles = videoFiles.Where(v => v.OriginalFileNameWithoutExtension == "WelcomeController").FirstOrDefault();
        mymodel.MyEnrollmentFiles = videoFiles.Where(v => v.OriginalFileNameWithoutExtension == "MyEnrollmentController").FirstOrDefault();
        mymodel.AdminSideFiles = videoFiles.Where(v => v.OriginalFileNameWithoutExtension == "AdminSideController").FirstOrDefault();
        return View(mymodel);
    }
```

As you can see I'm using `mymodel.` to build the model and I can access this in the view using:

```
@Model.LoginFiles.EnglishVideoURL
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample models you provided, your common model object can look like this

```
public class VideoUrlModel {    
    public string EnglishVideoUrl { get; set; }
    public string SpanishVideoUrl { get; set; }
}
```

The `GetVideoUrls` can then be updated as follows

```
private IEnumrable<VideoUrlModel> GetVideoUrls(string mimetype) {
    var VideoService = new AppServices.Video.GetAllVideoByMimeType();
    var videoFiles = VideoService.Execute(mimetype); 
    var models = videoFiles.Select(row => 
                       new VideoUrlModel { 
                              EnglishVideoUrl = row.englishvideourl,
                              SpanishVideoUrl = row.spanishvideourl
                       });
    return models;
}
```

Since `VideoService.Execute` returns `IEnumerable<dynamic>` you can iterate over the rows using the **LINQ** `Select` extension and create the model items as needed.

So now in your controller can pass the collection to the view as its model

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    //Use mimetype as key to find correct rows
    var mimetype = "mcv";
    var LookupData = GetVideoUrls(mimetype);
    return View(LookupData);
}
```

your view will expect the model as,

```
@model IEnumerable<VideoUrlModel>
```

and have access to the collection passed as the model for the view

Comment: I understand this now.  Question though, I have multiple rows with the two column names of englishvideourl and spanishvideourl.  how do I refence each row, then the column for that row?

Comment: Depends on what `VideoService.Execute` returns. I made assumptions as to what it returned and I had asked on the OP but you haven't given a response yet. So what type does it return?

Comment: I updated the original question with that code for `videoservice.execute`.  It returns a dynamic of all rows that match the criteria of mimetype=.

Comment: @JeffMcbride I get the dynamic part. I'm trying to understand what's behind that dynamic. as its not a concrete type I'll just be guessing what the properties are. At this point I don't know how your repository is mapping the columns to properties. You see my point?

Comment: I think I do.  I updated the question with the repository.  Does this help?  DBTableMNodel is just my connection strings to the database.